# Число в предложении: прописью или цифрами?

Tags: числительные, цифры

В каком случае нужно писать число прописью, а в каком — цифрами?

**Три банки вкусного варенья.

Буратино потерял 5 золотых.**

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю. Помимо правила о начале предложения есть рекомендация в не сугубо технических текстах писать "буквами" числа от 1 до 9. В другом варианте - от 1 до 20 и прочие, требующие только одного слова.
В художественных же текстах цифр вообще стоит по возможности избегать, если только это не номера телефонов или что-то подобное по количеству требуемых слов.
Все сказанное - не закон, а довольно мягкая рекомендация.

Написание в юридических, финансово-бухгалтерских, коммерческих, складских и некоторых других видах документов обычно регулируется специальными инструкциями, частично представленными по ссылке Людмилы.

Answer (score 4):

В начале предложения пишут только прописью, в середине можно цифрами, а можно и прописью, в документах (канцелярских) - и так и так: сначала цифрами, потом расшифровываем прописью.

Подробнее здесь: [Формы написания чисел в тексте документов | delo-press.ru](http://www.delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5297/)

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть у Розенталя "Способы оформления числительных на письме"

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/31.htm

Также: ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ НАПИСАНИЯ ЧИСЕЛ И ЗНАКОВ В ДОКУМЕНТАХ
http://www.doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.13

Answer (score 0):

Правила такого нет. Есть рекомендация поступать таким образом в изданиях популярных, газетно-журнальных, учебных (уровня средней школы). Во всех остальных случаях, когда издание серьезное, то там тяготеют к цифрам во всех случаях, словами пишут в редких случаях, при соблюдении единообразия. В художественной литературе предпочтение отдается словесной записи, там вопрос единообразия не стоит.